# Should I downvote questions posted on the wrong SE site?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, off-topic

If a question is not directly "bad", but placed on the wrong SE network (e.g., posted on stackoverflow.com when it should have been posted on superuser.com), in addition to close-voting, should I also downvote the question? Or not?

Comment: Do you think *How much eggs do I use for waffle batter* is useful to have on the front-page of SO?

Comment: @rene no, not at all.

Comment: Three down votes will remove it from the front page and there are way more down voters then close voters so that still is a viable option. Down voting prevents that other cooks go ask questions on SO as well and less people are invited to answer *6 to 8 eggs will do*.

Comment: @rene Doesn't disappearing require a net score of -4?  Pretty sure answers just get greyed out at -3, at least at Arqade.

Comment: @fbueckert being off-by-one isn't unfamiliar to me ...

Answer (score -1):

I generally do not downvote a question that is a good question, but merely submitted to the wrong stack. I will flag/VTC the question, and will sometimes explain *why* the question is inappropriate for the stack.

If the question is on a topic that belongs on a different stack, but would likely be closed on the “correct” stack for various poor-quality-related reasons, I will flag/VTC for a reason *other* than it being on the wrong stack, and *will* comment that the topic belongs on [whatever-stack], but would not be acceptable there in the present form because [reasons].